# Android APK file and DEX files not created, with no warning or error

Tags: android, eclipse, bin

I've developed Android for a while now, using WIN7 64bit and Eclipse.
Since I've tried to install the new ADT (1.5), I get a very weird phenomena. My build doesn't complete, and doesn't generate the APK file, nor the dex files.
the class files are created, but nothing else.

Also, there is no warning or error neither at the output or the Eclipse log.

The problem didn't occur immediately, but only after 1 or 2 good builds.
Even if I create a simple project, the same thing happens.

I didn't find anything useful on the net.
I've re-downloaded Eclipse, the SDK, ADT, and started all over again, and got the JRE7 compatibility issue (function ... must override).
I guess I got a Java SE update, and lost the old JRE. So I've downloaded JRE6, changed the compliance issue, and set it and the environment, and got back to square 1 :)

The build process starts, reaches 50% or 75%, suddenly stops, and no apk or dex files are created.
Even for new empty helloWorld projects.

Can someone please help? I have no idea how to proceed.

Thanks

Comment: have you tried building from the command prompt instead of using Eclipse's built in export feature? http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-sign-apk-zip-files/

Answer (score 38, accepted):

"With the new ADT plugins, it is the default behavior (to speed up
build time) to not generate the .apk on every build..." as said in groups.google:

See http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/769628c57caa51ad/4cb2c6589995a9a5?pli=1

You can enable automatic dex/apk building in the Eclipse settings:
  Window -> Preferences -> Android -> Build -> [] Skip packaging and dexing...

// I tried to reinstall everything before finding this solution....

Comment: thanks you saved my life, i will +1 this (for today my vote up limit has reached)

Comment: This helped me out a lot. I don't remember updating my Eclipse but suddenly it stopped re-making the apks on clean. +1

Comment: the feature could at least give us a "build now" option to override it :-P

Answer (score 2):

you can also simply change the jdk version forcing it to rebuild: right click on project -> properties -> Java COmpiler -> on right side pane, click on check box for "Enable project specific settings", then select Compiler compliance level: 1.6 or something else than current.

It will rebuild and re-generate the apk and dex files. :) It helped me at least.

Answer (score 0):

This problem wasted a lot of my time, I was getting the following error

adb is running normally.
Could not find .apk!

I got this fixed by following 2 steps:

1. In Eclipse >Windows>Preferences>Android>Build, uncheck "Skip packaging and dexing ...."
2. In the project properties>Android, I unchecked isLibrary.

Answer (score 0):

Just run it on your emulate (Right click your project -> Run As-> Android application) then check your bin folder.